# Create FOREIGN KEY to versioned table

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys

I have version logic in tables. So, each table contains 'is_deleted' and 'version' fields. ('version' field is referenced to single table with all versions)

```
table1(id, field1_1, field1_2, is_deleted, version[fk to versions.id])
table2(id, field2_1, field2_2, table1_id, is_deleted, version[fk to versions.id])
versions(id, main_version)
```

When I get records from db I use where clause for each of referenced table and for table itself. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE (
  (
    (t1.id, t1."version") IN 
    (SELECT sub_t1.id, max(sub_t1."version") FROM table AS sub_t1 GROUP by sub_t1.id)
  ) 
  AND t1.is_deleted IS FALSE
)
```

For MySQL you can change condition for 'is_deleted' to

```
is_deleted = 0
```

Now, I'm adding new tables and I want to use foreign keys, but foreign key can reference only unique column, but id is not unique (it is kept through versions) and I can't use complex key, because new version created only when smth changed and only for that record.

Should I omit FK or should I add additional table with only one column id for each of versioned tables? Will adding such tables offer some benefit except for data integrity? Adding such tables will make logic more complicated.

So, should I live it untouched or make smth like this:

```
table1_ids(id)
table1_versions(id, table1_id[fk to table1_ids.id], ...)
table2_versions(id, ..., table1_id[fk to table1_ids.id],...)
table2_ids(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you rather create schema for every version ?
It will be much more clean solution.

Comment: I have rather big set of data - about 15000 of records (for connected part of tables). So it is not good to copy full set if single field in one record have changed. And such change can occure in records each hour. And if I will cre

Comment: After your answer I'm thinking about possibility to store previous values(in case of change) in separate table, because 99% of records have only one version (for currently active main_version) so I can use FK to main_version instead of version and then include it to PK, but it will double quantity of tables...